# Why is the empty document an error?

Tags: errors, rubber

I'm using Pluma (basically gedit) with a plugin I found to help with tex documents and it does this very well, I just started a new one and activated the preview (because I'll want it at some point) and I have found that an empty document is an error!

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This gives an error about the PDF file not existing, why?

Is it some bug, what could possibly require there to be text for it to work? Adding even a single letter fixes this.

The engine used was "rubber" by the way.

Comment: There is an "error" - the file doesn't exist. I spoke about an error not something that was erroneous. This is still helpful though, thank you. __addendum__ the PDF reader isn't upset, `rubber` is. @egreg

Answer (score 13):

The LaTeX code you show produces no page, so no PDF file is written. The PDF viewer can't find it, because it doesn't exist.

It is no error on the LaTeX side; if the front-end is not able to manage the situation, it's a problem of the front-end.

Doing

```
pdflatex teal && echo $?
```

where `teal.tex` is your example file, the terminal reports

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./teal.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./teal.aux)
(./teal.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on teal.log.
0
```

so it's evident that the exit code is 0 (no error).

A program such as `rubber` (which has been unmantained for several years) or `latexmk` will signal you a non zero exit code, because they *expect* some output and *assume* that a missing PDF file is due to some error. This is wrong, in my opinion, because they *could* examine the exit code of the `pdflatex` process (which is only 0 or 1, by the way).

In this case `latexmk` exits with code 12, but, again, this is *not* a TeX/LaTeX error. And I don't think there's a workaround, other than making a feature request/bug report to the developers. You'll probably be unlucky with `rubber`.

Answer (score 6):

As @egreg says in the answer: If you don't make PDFLaTeX shipout any page, it cannot produce a PDF, since by PDF specs, it has to contain a page.

Even if you could make a PDF file with no pages, it is a fair decision of PDFLaTeX designers that no PDF file is produced. Because in some cases you don't want any ocument to be produced, for example when running `.dtx`/`.ins` file to produce a package `.sty` file, or when running `makebst`. However, in such cases, it makes no sense to use `pdflatex`, one should use `latex` or `tex`, depending on which is the proper format to be used in each case.

And needed to add, there's a big difference between no page and one empty page, from the point of view of TeX core. Notice that `pdftex` won't produce any page with this code:

```
\bye
```

(Yes, that was a complete plain-TeX document). However, it will produce a page with only the page number (and one empty whence invisible paragraph if you care) in this case:

```
\leavevmode\bye
```

So producing an empty page from an empty document would be a non-sense.

### TL;DR

To answer your question: Why `rubber` treats it as an error? Because its designers/programmers chose it so.